# SMS app for typing long texts

Tags: android, sms

The default Android app for SMS text messaging shows only 4 lines of text in a small box while typing. My messages are often much longer, and often I can not see the beginning of my sentence even. This makes it very difficult to type anything longer than a few words.

I have used the app Textra for a couple of years now, which is much better, giving 7-8 lines (iirc) of text. The message is still within in a small box though.
Is there an even better app for typing long messages?

When the screen is long/high, with lots of space for text, why should a new message be contained within a tiny box at the bottom of the screen. It doesn't make any sense not to be able to use the whole screen for typing new text messages. In all SMS apps I've seen, you have to scroll up and down inside that small text box in order to check the message while typing.

Edit (after a week): Going with Chomp for now. Better than the Google standard app at least, getting 8 long lines of text instead of 4 half length. Looked at the standard Samsung app: The visible text area while typing is huge, you can see much more of your text than any other sms-app I've seen. Tried finding it on Google Play to install it on my Sony -- no luck.

Comment: why you don't use google message app ?

Comment: @PratikFagadiya it has same limitation - only 4 lines?

Comment: you could write long text in your notes and click send, then choose sms and select contact

Comment: @PratikFagadiya - Google Message is the standard app, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @alecxs - That could work - using a notes app. Definitely a better solution for seeing the whole text I'm typing.  It would be better though, to be able to scroll up and down the whole thread of messages while typing, instead of changing between two different apps.